# Error while building MFP Cordova Mproject

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I am facing an issue integrating cordova plugin into IBM Mobilefirst 7.1 Hybrid application. We followed the IBM Knowledge and created MFP Cordova project, integrated custom cordova plugin into the project. But while building the project we are getting build error. During build it is not able to reference classes from aar files that is there in cordova plugin.

```
  What build tool does mfp cli uses to build cordova project? Can we change it any other build tool.
```

Answer (score 0):

Cordova applications creating using MobileFirst CLI 7.1 generate Cordova projects that are based on Cordova 3.6, which is somewhat outdated.

You cannot replace the Cordova version that is added when using the MobileFirst CLI 7.1. This in turn may limit the plugins you are able to use, so my suggestion is:

1. Pick the plugins that are compatible with the mentioned Cordova 3.6, or
2. Consider upgrading to MobileFirst Foundation 8, with which you are now no longer restricted by tools provided by IBM. You create the Cordova application using the Cordova CLI (not MobileFirst CLI). You then add the MobileFirst SDK to the application like any other Cordova plug-in.

Learn more about Cordova applications in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/cordova-tutorials/

Comment: Thank you Idan for the response. I am currently using the second approach. I am getting the below error. {status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", responseText: "Error 404: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io… not found: /api/adapters/ServiceAdapter/doLogin↵", responseHeaders: Object, errorMsg: "Not Found"…}errorCode: "UNEXPECTED_ERROR"errorMsg: "Not Found"responseHeaders: ObjectresponseText: "Error 404: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /api/adapters/ServiceAdapter/doLogin↵"status: 404statusText: "Not Found"__proto__: Object}.

Comment: It is not taking the runtime specified in wlclient.properties.

Comment: Your question is not clear and it has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: Can we use cordova-plugin-mfp for creating mfp cordova project that can run on Mobilefirst 7.1?

Comment: You cannot. The SDK and security framework are incompatible.